# Importance of using function

Tags: c, function, memory

It has been on my mind for a while now.
How is space managed when we use a function.
Particularly this:

```
main()
{
    printf("Helloworld");
}
```

and this:

```
void fun()
{
    printf("Helloworld");
}
main()
{   
    fun();    
}
```

So in terms of memory consumption are both of these the same? Or one of them is consuming lesser memory.

I understand that in a large program functions help us not repeating the same codes again and again AND also it releases its space every time it ends, But I want to know what happens in a small program where memory consumption is insignificantly small where the memory release of function after it ends has no significant effect.

What are the pro's and con's of function in this case

Comment: the optimizer will inline the function. Compare no optimization (`-O0`) https://godbolt.org/z/xrbYGz6PM with optimizations turned up (`-O2`) https://godbolt.org/z/vr9dr7od5

Comment: It's likely that a modern compiler will produce exactly the same code for the two example codes presented.

Comment: You are optimizing too soon. Write your program, profile performance, ***then optimize***. A compiler will likely take care of this for you.

Comment: Please use a more orthodox indentation style for C.
I strongly recommend either Allmann (which is what I use, more or less)
or some version of 1TBS (which is used by many other people).
See Wikipedia on [Indentation
Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for information
about the variants.

Comment: Note that all C standards except C90 require the compiler to generate a diagnostic message for `fun()`  because you do not specify the return type.  You should be using `static void fun(void) { … }` which gives the compiler the chance to inline the function body.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard doesn't tell anything about memory consumption when using a function. An implementation (i.e. a specific compiler on a specific computer system) is free to do function calls the way it wants. It's even allowed to suppress function calls and put the functions code directly where the call was (called: inline). So there is no answer that will cover all systems in all situations.

Most systems uses a stack for handling function calls. A stack is a pre-allocated memory block that is assigned to the program at start up. The running program keeps track of the memory used within that block using a stack pointer. When a function is called, the stack pointer is changed according to the memory requirement for the function. When the function returns, the stack pointer is changed back to the original value. This allows for fast allocation and deallocation of variables local to the function and also any overhead memory used for the call itself (e.g. for storing a return address, cpu registers, etc.).

Since the stack is a pre-allocated fixed memory block, there is really no extra memory consumption involved in a function call. It's only a matter of using the already allocated memory.

However, if you do many nested function calls, you may run out of stack memory but that's another issue.